# Cannot read bluetooth data from Bluetooth Serial Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, bluetooth

I wrote the following code to display received Bluetooth data in an alert message in the application.

```
open(item: any){
alert("Selected ");
this.bluetoothSerial.connectInsecure("XX:XX:X4:X6:1X:2X").subscribe((data) =>{
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  this.bluetoothSerial.subscribeRawData().subscribe((data) => { alert("Subscription : " + JSON.stringify(data))});
});
setTimeout(() => {
  this.bluetoothSerial.read().then((data) => { alert("read data : " +JSON.stringify(data))});
}, 2000);
}
```

When a Bluetooth signal is sent, "Subscription" alert box and "read data" alert box both display null strings and actual sent data is not displayed. How to configure Ionic Bluetooth Serial package to display received Bluetooth data?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove your timeout and call read() inside subscribeRawData() as follows:

```
open(item: any){
alert("Selected ");
this.bluetoothSerial.connectInsecure("XX:XX:X4:X6:1X:2X").subscribe((data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    this.bluetoothSerial.subscribeRawData().subscribe((data) => { 
            alert("Subscription : " + JSON.stringify(data));
            this.bluetoothSerial.read().then((data) => { alert("read data : " +JSON.stringify(data))});
        });
    });
}
```